# /node - 404 or 301?

Tags: 6

All the suggestions I've seen for getting rid of that stupid /node page involve programmatically disabling it altogether. Is there a specific reason nobody suggests to 301 it to, say, the home page? It seems to me it'd be smarter to teach web crawlers not to visit the page than send them into a dead end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it only makes sense to use a 301 if you have already been using /node as a page other than the home page, so it has already been indexed by search engines. If you're building a new site, or if your site has been using /node only as front page, then it has not been indexed and you can safely tell users and search engines that the page does not exist.